# assign values to object via loop and then make it object again

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Idea is to create an Component with a child which could be any component, so i need to assign the props to this Component.

I try to do it in a loop, because i don't know how many props there should be

```
//Array of objects which i wanna render
{array?.[i] && (
    <Component
        {...Object.keys(component.props)?.map(prop => ({
            [prop]: array?.[i]?.[prop]
        }))}
    />
)}
```

but as result in inspector i got something like..

```
props
0:{prop1: "prop1"}
1:{prop2: "prop2"}
2:{prop3: "prop3"}
```

But i wan't to look it like this

```
prop1: "prop1",
prop2: "prop2"
prop3: "prop3"
```

Comment: It's a bit confusing to me what the actual loop does, but I suspect `Object.fromEntries` can help here.

Comment: Well, Array.prototype.map() returns an array.

Comment: @Evert It takes the props object from Component and loop through it, then assign the values to it which i have in object which i wanna render

Answer (score 0):

burned out a bit

all i tried to do is like

```
<Component
    {...Object.keys(component.props)?.reduce((acc: { [key: string]: any }, curr) => {
    acc[curr] = array?.[i]?.[curr]
    return acc
    }, {})}
/>
```